# How to force a tableView to creep under navigationBar?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, transparent, navigationbar

I have a tableView that I want to show under the top bar or the navigationBar, I mean to make it start under the top bar as if it was not there, because my navigationBar is transparent. This is basically how they do it lately in the iOS Music app when you are checking an album. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets after clicking on your viewController in the Storyboard.